# Snowflake: In a MERGE or COPY command (from external stage) can I specify that only the newest csv file should be merged/copied?

Tags: amazon-s3, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, boomi

Right now, our MERGE/COPY commands point to an s3 folder. Anytime there's more than a single csv file in the S3 folder, Snowflake throws a "duplicate rows" error.
I manually move s3 files each morning so that there's only ever one file in the s3 folder.
How can I tell snowflake to only MERGE/COPY the newest csv file in the folder?
(NOTE: date/time is part of our naming convention for these csv files)

Comment: DevOps might get you more attention.

Comment: Snowflake copy command should remember the file it processed in its metadata. We do this all the time. Can you paste the copy command,file sample and error so that I can replicate this in my environment ?

Comment: To answer this best we need more information.  How are you executing your COPY INTO commands? Are you doing it through Snowflake Tasks/Stored Procedure, via Snowpipe, or an outside tool? Like the above comment mentions, Snowflake keeps track of what data has been copied over from a Stage.  So we need more info to understand your problem.

Comment: @CodeMonkey We're using Dell Boomi to trigger SQL commands in Snowflake. 
The stage is an S3 bucket, and then the various COPY INTO commands also specify a partial directory path. The problem arises anytime there's more than one file in the specified S3 folder. These files are usually different versions of the same data, and so the PKs overlap between files. Can I tell Snowflake to only copy the newest file it can find in the S3 folder?

Comment: @EvanJennings added an answer. Hopefully it is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using Dell Boomi to execute your COPY INTO command, are multiple files coming into your S3 bucket in the same load or are they incrementally loading?

If they are incrementally loading I would set PURGE = TRUE on your COPY INTO statement so that once the file is correctly copied it is deleted from your S3 bucket and when the next file comes in there won't be a conflict copying to your stage table. PURGE = TRUE requires you to make sure permissions are setup correctly to allow Snowflake to delete from your S3.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#purging-files-after-loading

You can also query try doing something like the following if you want to try and get really clever:

```
COPY INTO YourTable
    (
    RAW_FILE_NAME
    , RAW_FILE_ROW_NUMBER
    , ColPK
    , ColVal
    , ColVal2
    )
  FROM (WITH CTE AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY metadata$filename DESC) AS rnk, metadata$filename, metadata$file_row_number, t.$1,t.$2,t.$3
        FROM @YourStage/YourDirectory/
        AS t) SELECT metadata$filename, metadata$file_row_number, $1,$2,$3 FROM CTE WHERE rnk = 1);
```